# SharePoint 2019 Prem Branding Classic and Modern

Tags: branding, modern-experience, classic-experience

I have an on Prem SharePoint site and deciding how to use Branding with the Modern site lists and pages.  I created a Master Page that changes the color and text of the top nav bar, replacing the word "SharePoint" with the company name. This works great on the Classic pages but not on Modern pages.

When a user has the option to change from Classic to Modern views in a list or page, also removes the CSS rendered on the Classic pages. The change of colors and text can be confusing.

Is there anyway to show brand consistency across the two templates other than force users to one or the other?